# if author meta is empty

Tags: wordpress

i am developing a multiauthor website using wp. I want to out put author meta in the single page. The output is working fine but to make it better, i want to output something else if the field is empty, especially for field that is not required such as website, twitter or facebook.

Basically i use this to output the field:

```
<strong>Website:</strong> <a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'website' ); ?>" target="_blank"></a></p>
```

What i want to do is if the author don't have any website, so i want to output something like "No website"

How to do this?
O yes, by default this field in wordpress is not empty, it just have content like "http://"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('website') != 'http://'): ?>
<strong>Website:</strong> <a href="<?php the_author_meta('website'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></p>
<?php else: ?>
<strong>No website</strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```